# Highchart Options (points' size) - R shiny

Tags: javascript, r, highcharts, shiny

I am a new user to shiny and try to train through the examples provided in the library. 
I have some troubles with the *highchart* options, my plot is a line with points, and I would like to control the size of the points.

Here is the simplified code: (using an example from the "highchart" library, folder "demo"):

**### START of the code**

```
library("shiny")
library("highcharter")

data(citytemp)

ui <- fluidPage(
    h1("Highcharter Demo"),
    fluidRow(
column(width = 4, class = "panel",
               selectInput("type", label = "Type", width = "100%",
                           choices = c("line", "column", "bar", "spline")), 
               selectInput("stacked", label = "Stacked",  width = "100%",
                           choices = c(FALSE, "normal", "percent")),
               selectInput("theme", label = "Theme",  width = "100%",
                           choices = c(FALSE, "fivethirtyeight", "economist",  "darkunica", "gridlight",
                                       "sandsignika", "null", "handdrwran", "chalk")
               )
        ),
        column(width = 8,
               highchartOutput("hcontainer",height = "500px")
        )
    )
)

server = function(input, output) {
    output$hcontainer <- renderHighchart({
        hc <- highcharts_demo() %>%
            hc_rm_series("Berlin") %>% 
            hc_chart(type = "line") %>% 
            hc_plotOptions(area = list(
                stacking = input$stacked,
                lineColor = "#ffffff",
                lineWidth = 1,
                marker = list(
                    lineWidth = 1,
                    radius=10,
                    lineColor = "#ffffff"
                )))%>% 
            hc_tooltip(pointFormat = '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>:
                       <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b> ({point.y:,.0f} millions)<br/>',
                       shared = TRUE)
        hc  
    })  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**## END of the code**

I have done some research and found out that you can control the size using "marker" and its options. But my chart looks completely independent from this feature: I tried several values of Width & radius for the marker and it does not change anything.

Can someone advise me on what I am doing wrong?
Many thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi your chart is a line, so in `hc_plotOptions` you should set options for a line, not an area, e.g. :

```
hc_plotOptions(
  line = list(                   # put line here instead of area 
    stacking = input$stacked,
    lineColor = "#ffffff",
    lineWidth = 1,
    marker = list(
      lineWidth = 1,
      radius=10,
      lineColor = "#ffffff"
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: Thank you ! works perfectly ! :)   (sorry for the delay, I answered the same day but looks like my answer has not been considered)